# Paginação Flexigrid

Tags: javascript

Tenho um flexigrid, que me retorna dados via xml. Porém se uso o LIMIT na query, ele me retorna somente aquele valor setado e não faz a paginação dos demais registros, se caso eu tiro o LIMIT, os botões next e prev funcionam, porém são exibidos todos os registros em uma só página.
Alguma ideia do que possa ser ? no console não é exibido nenhum erro.
Obrigado desde já !